# Search an attribute for a substring

Tags: ruby

I am trying to remove all whitespaces from an object's attribute that contains a given substring. For example, I have an object `event` and attributes: `4IP2`, `3IP5`, `2IP1`. I would like to do the following:

```
event[4IP2].gsub(/\s+/, '')
```

in a generic manner, i.e.,

```
event[*IP*].gsub(/\s+/, '')
```

which should work for all attributes `4IP2`, `3IP5`, `2IP1`. Appreciate any help.

Comment: `4IP2`, etc. are not valid ruby expressions. It is not clear what `event` is.

Comment: Event is the name of an object, and 4IP2, 3IP5 are attributes of this object.

Comment: I'm afraid it's till not clear.  Could you please edit the question to show both the input and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the attributes in-place:

```
event.each {|k,v| v.gsub!(/\s+/, '') if /IP/ =~ k}
```

Otherwise, to create a copy:

```
Hash[event.map {|k,v| [k, /IP/ =~ k ? v.gsub(/\s+/, '') : v]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that `event` is a hash, here you go:

```
▶ event = { '4IP2' => 'a b c', '3GG5' => 'ffff f', '2IP1' => 'ggg   ' }
▶ event.map { |k, v| [k, /IP/ =~ k ? v.delete(' ') : v] }.to_h
#⇒ { "2IP1" => "ggg", "3GG5" => "ffff f", "4IP2" => "abc" }
```